# How do I connect to my mysql databases, which I used heidsql to make, from a website?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using heidisql to create my mysql databases. How do i connect to those databases from the website I'm using. I need to be able to change the databases from the website. 
I am writing the website in php and writing the program that interacts with the databases in python. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: how is related how you created your mysql database? do you have any knowledge in php/python? have you worked with databases before?

Comment: no I haven't. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP's MySQL functions.
Or you can use the PEAR DB package, it makes things much easier. If you don't already use PEAR you will have to install it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can interact directly with the database using PHP's builtin MySQL functions: [PHP MySQL Docs](http://php.net/system)

Alternatively, you can write all of the database interaction in Python, then have your PHP website call those Python scripts, using PHP's [system function](http://php.net/system).